# Avoiding inverse matrix calculation in Hessian approximation in Davidson-Flatcher-Powell method formula

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, inverse, numerical-optimization, hessian-matrix

My general concern is regarding denominator computation in this part 
$$\frac{s_ks_k^T}{y_k^Ts_k}\tag{1}$$
of the Hessian update in the method's algorithm/formula.

Formula has taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davidon%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Powell_formula) :

$$H_{k+1} = H_{k}- \frac{s_ks_k^T}{y_k^Ts_k}\tag{1} + \frac{H_{k}y_{k}y_{k}^TH_{k}}{y_k^TH_{k}y_{k}} $$

So, there definitely denominator will be a matrix. To calculate the equation, there is a need to find the inverse of all division, and, obviously saying, find the inverse of the denominator matrix.

Are there any ways to avoid calculating the inverse matrix?
Or maybe there is some way to approximate the inverse matrix in this case?

Because of brute force matrix inversion approach is not working at all, because of computational issues.

I have seen one [C++ implementation](http://www.mymathlib.com/optimization/nonlinear/unconstrained/fletcher_powell_davidon.html) where we calculating this dividend as the inner product of 2 vectors.
And I think that is not correct at all.

What I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $y_k,\, s_k$ are meant to be $n\times 1$ matrices then $y_k^Ts_k$ as the dot product makes perfect sense. Maybe a thing you're missing here is that you see such notation first time? Why is the other denominator OK in that sense?

Comment: As per  @Alexey Burdin , both denominators evaluate to scalars. $y_k$ and $s_k$ are n by 1 vectors, $H_k$ and $H_{k+1}$ are n by n matrices.